# Hide SharePoint ribbon(based on permission) using java script injunction without changing master page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, ribbon, custom-actions

I have SharePoint online site I need to hide **`SP ribbon`** based on user permission.
Should not change the master page code.

anyone suggest me to achieve this or creating the new control to inject in all pages.

Comment: I assume just classic pages because you mention master pages? 
how many pages can you just add a content editor web part to each page with the script loaded?
Are you asking how to do it with the script or just how to inject script?

Comment: Is there any OOTB control to hide ribbon for all pages?  like, JSON or javascript ribbon controls..etc

Answer (score 1):

For classic view, you could add custom script link for this requirement.

```
Connect-PNPOnline -Url https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/
Add-PnPJavaScriptLink -Name "hideNavigationBasedonGroup" -Url /sites/xxx/SiteAssets/yourJShideribbon.js -Sequence 9999 -Scope Site
```

You could find the script [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/healthvault/en-us/979b2bda-30d4-482f-ae56-fce5f98573c8/forum-faq-hide-sharepoint-list-ribbon-command-based-on-user-groups?forum=sharepointdevelopment)